# How to subscribe to observable one after another

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a list of GraphQL request for example

```
const req1 = this.updateUserGQL
        .mutate(
          { input: {name: 'x'} }
        )
.
.
.
const reqn = this.updateUserGQL
        .mutate(
          { input: {name: 'y'} }
        )

const requests = [req1, req2, req3, ... reqn]
```

For my use case, I need to subscribe the requests one after another i.e first subscribe req1, then subscribe req2 only if req1 finished or gave an error and so on. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [`concat`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) rxjs operator to ensure each observable is completed before proceeding to the next one.

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';

concat(
  req1, 
  req2, 
  req3, 
  ... reqn
)
.subscribe(/* Action */);
```